# Android - Event does not have parameter "firebase_screen_class" and no default value was defined. Returning "undefined"

Tags: android, firebase-analytics

Getting this warning from firebase in Android :

```
Event does not have parameter "firebase_screen_class" and no default value was defined. Returning "undefined".
```

As of my knowledge Screen_Class should be automatically added to the events especially screen event.

Current firebase-analytics version is : 20.1.0

Answer (score 1):

You might have disabled the screenview tracking. On Android, make sure to nest the following setting within the  tag of the AndroidManifest.xml file:

`<meta-data android:name="google_analytics_automatic_screen_reporting_enabled" android:value="true" />`

Comment: if you dont want see your gtm log on logcat,u should edit value be "false"